# Rails Data Callback Posting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, post, callback, request

As part of my rails application users can make a donation to our charity. I simply link the users to an external form on the payment processing company's website, with our unique ID in the params. Once a transaction is successful it redirects back to a URL on my application.

As part of this process, the information filled out on the form, email address, donation amount etc should be posted back to the URL on my site. The information is posted back as a form post. I have set a route for the URL as a post request. I'm currently looking at the headers but I cannot see the information, so far I have tried:

```
<%= params %>
<%= request.POST %>
<%= request.headers %>
<%= request.env["HTTP_ACCEPT"] %>
<%= request.env["HTTP_HOST"] %>
<%= request.env["HTTP_USER_AGENT"] %>
```

How can I now access the information? Speaking with my friend he says the information should be in the HTTP headers but I'm not sure what I should be doing to be able to view it. I need to check if the transaction was successful which should return a `'transStatus'` with a value of Y/N.

Any help appreciated, apologies I am new to this.

Thanks

Lee

Answer (score 0):

If the information is being `POST`ed back to your application you should be able to access them via the Rails `params` hash, as in

```
params[:transStatus]
```

and so on. In your callback action, try to inspect the `params` hash and see what it contains.

If you want to deal with the raw post data directly you can use [`ActionDispatch::Request`'s `raw_post`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Request.html#method-i-raw_post) method instead.

Edit: If you want to access the request's headers you can do so with [`ActionDispatch::Request`'s `headers`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Request.html#method-i-headers) method instead. It just provides a hash-like structure with all request headers. Feel free to inspect, iterate, and access the ones you need!

As a concrete example, and assuming that the header you expect is `'transStatus'`, you could do something like that in your callback action (controller lever):

```
success = (request.headers['transStatus'] == 'Y') ? true : false

if success
  # transaction succeeded - success path here...
else
  # failure path
end
```

If you are not sure if it is `transStatus` then you have to consult the API of the external service, ask its developer, or simply debug it yourself by inspecting the request you receive (`headers` and `params`).

Comment: there is no transStatus param. Doing <%= params %> will output all params, I can only see controller and action. I have however tried individually anyway and still nothing. I need to get the info from the HTTP headers I'm guessing but not sure exactly what code to use to get this. Any furhter help on the Raw post method?

Comment: Try `p params.inspect` in your controller action to ensure that the information you need isn't already there. I will update my answer to cover how to access the request's headers.

Comment: thank you for updating answer. I realise this is the code I need to use. Maybe my question is not worded correctly. My question is: where will the callback data be posted to? / How can I access this? / Will it be in the HTTP headers? / Will it be an env variable somewhere / Will it be a log file I have to access? Apparently it's a similar setup to the way paypal does data callbacks. I am not experienced in it at all so don't know

Comment: You mentioned in your question that the data will be posted back to your application. I assume you can define your custom callback URL in this provider you use. Then you create the corresponding route, controller, and action, and within this action you can access the POSTed data as I describe in my answer. This is an asynchronous process, you don't know exactly when the data will be POSTed back to you - it's a callback from a 3rd party. Your action should implement the business logic of what happens once/when the data are posted.